# Sort a complex nested dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.9

Consider this dictionary format, how do I sort this complex nested dictionary by The WEIGHT or HEIGHT key:

```
People = {
     'person1': {
          'name': 'John Cena',
          'size': {
              'height': 175,
              'weight': 100
           }
      },
      'person2': {
          'name': 'Chuck Norris',
           'size': {
               'height': 180,
               'weight': 90
           }
      },
      'person3': {
          'name': 'Jon Skeet',
          'size': {
              'height': 185,
              'weight': 110
          }
      }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Dictionaries can't be sorted, but `.items()` returns a list of key/value pairs.  Use the `key` parameter of `sorted` to indicate the field to sort on.  Python 3.7 and later allow dicts to maintain insertion order, so converting the result back to a dict will be ordered:

```py
>>> People = { 'person1': { 'name': 'John Cena', 'size': { 'height': 175, 'weight': 100 } }, 'person2': { 'name': 'Chuck Norris', 'size': { 'height': 180, 'weight': 90 } }, 'person3': { 'name': 'Jon Skeet', 'size': { 'height': 185, 'weight': 110 } } }
>>> dict(sorted(People.items(),key=lambda x: x[1]['size']['weight']))
{'person2': {'name': 'Chuck Norris', 'size': {'height': 180, 'weight': 90}}, 'person1': {'name': 'John Cena', 'size': {'height': 175, 'weight': 100}}, 'person3': {'name': 'Jon Skeet', 'size': {'height': 185, 'weight': 110}}}
```